# How to shuffle column cells vertically with sql?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm using sqlite with python. Suppose that I have a datatable that looks like this:

```
Name   | Age
_______|____
Mike   | 12
Jack   | 45
Ben    | 37
Anne   | 19
```

**Question:** Is it possible (using sqlite) to shuffle the columns vertically? If so, how? I want my datatable to look something like this (I don't care about the order in which cells in the "age" column get shuffled):

```
Name   | Age
_______|____
Mike   | 45
Jack   | 12
Ben    | 19
Anne   | 37
```

Comment: What do you mean `shuffled` in your result set?

Comment: @D-Shih Thanks for your reply! I want to change the order of the "age" column w.r.t. the "name" column. In other words: I want to reassign the ages to the names, based on the ages in the "age" column.

Comment: Is there any logic on shuffle or random?

Comment: @D-Shih It's not important to me, so either is fine!

Comment: What's your sqlite version does it support CTE or window function?

Comment: @D-Shih My version is 3.16.0. I'm not sure!

Comment: I write an answer you can try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to your SQLite version didn't support `window function` and `CTE`, so you can try to create a temp table to carry your data and `ROWID` and `random()`.

Create a `randomRn` colunm base on `random()`, then `JOIN` the table by `ROWID` and `randomRn` number (random rowID)

**Schema (SQLite v3.16)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  Age INT
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Mike', 12);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Jack', 45);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Ben', 37);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Anne', 19);

CREATE TABLE temp1 
AS 
SELECT AGE,Name,ROWID,random() rn
FROM T
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t1.Name name,t2.Age age
FROM temp1 t1 JOIN 
(
  SELECT *,(
    select count(*) 
    from temp1 tt
    where tt.rn >= t1.rn
  ) randomRn
  FROM temp1 t1
) t2 on t1.rowid = t2.randomRn;

| name | age |
| ---- | --- |
| Ben  | 12  |
| Anne | 45  |
| Mike | 37  |
| Jack | 19  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ewotpCyPsXHj6PR8mmXqG8/1)

**NOTE**

remember `DROP` the temp table when you finish using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sql, just replace your table name at 2 places in below query and see the result.

```
 select name, max ( age) age 
 from ( select name,  age from ( select name, null age  from temp_person  order by random() ) 
       union all 
        select name, age from ( select  name, age from temp_person order by random() )  )
 group by name
```